# center 3 divs, with same height

Tags: html, css

How do I place 3 div's side by side with same height

I want to make that:

```
[LEFT][   CENTER   ][RIGHT]
[LEFT][   CENTER   ][RIGHT]
[LEFT][   CENTER   ][RIGHT]
[LEFT][   CENTER   ][RIGHT]
```

I've got:

```html
<div id="container">
  <div style="float:left;">Left</div>
  <div style="float:right;">Right</div>
  <div id="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

and it ends up  with

```
[  LEFT][    CENTER    ][ RIGHT]
[  LEFT][    CENTER    ][ RIGHT]
[CENTER][    CENTER    ][CENTER]
[CENTER][    CENTER    ][CENTER]
[CENTER][    CENTER    ][CENTER]
```

or

```
[  LEFT][    CENTER    ][ RIGHT]
[  LEFT][    CENTER    ][ RIGHT]
[  LEFT][bodybackground][ RIGHT]
[  LEFT][bodybackground][ RIGHT]
[  LEFT][bodybackground][ RIGHT]
```

EDIT: I want all divs to have same height despite different content height

Comment: Can you use display:inline-block;height:100px; instead of float?

Comment: You can use the CSS [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to manage that easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if your HTML can be changed but if you change the order of the div's for left center and right like in my code, then flex-box is a very clean way to do this.

CODE:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

#container>div {
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="container">
    <div>left</div>
    <div>center</div>
    <div>right</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: that worked for me, thanks.
PS: Will this solution give me extra problem when  adding responsiveness later?

Comment: it wont, it will actually make your life much easier.
add: "flex-wrap: wrap;" to #container and the elements will automatically slide to the bottom if they cant fit side by side

Comment: how do I make right div stick to the right side? (when center div has almost no content all divs may take no more than 50% of the width) what exactly i need is 250px left div, 250px right div and a center div which has same width no matter if it has content

Comment: could you answer please?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, i do not understand your question fully. You want all the divs to always have the same width? or you want your center div to have the same width as the other divs? If you create a codepen i might be able to understand what is going wrong and help you :)

Comment: I found solution, margin:auto for middle div is ok for me

Answer (score 3):

Don't use float, use for `left:0px;` and `right:0px;`

For the height, use `height: 0;position: relative;padding-bottom: 70%;`

By the way If you are not that good with css, I recommend you to use bootstrap, and simply make what you want with

```
<div style="col-md-2"></div>
<div style="col-md-8"></div>
<div style="col-md-2"></div>
```

and the height property I told you about.

Comment: Good suggestion with Bootstrap. Notably, version prior to 4 are using float for positioning and need some additional CSS and classes for the columns to have the same height. Version 4, on the other hand, uses flexbox, so by only applying ".align-items-stretch" to the parent div will result in the desired effect.

Comment: @Siavas Thanks for completing the answer

Comment: i tried using left/right but it ended up with all divs being one under the other and they were all in left (i have no idea why). I'm not familiar with bootstrap and i think im not gonna use it yet.
.. left div is 250px width, right 200px

Comment: That's the thing about bootstrap it is really simple to use, fully responsive and really useful, check a simple tutorial at w3schools https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp it's worth it believe me... @K.Mamyk

Comment: @artiom if i dont use bootstrap now will it be a problem to add it later?

Comment: @K.Mamyk No, as you sere in the tutorial bootstrap is really easy to implement on your code, but still it takes some time if you convert everything to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:table` and `display:table-cell` instead of `float`

```css
.container{display:table; width:100%}
.container div {display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;}
.container div:first-child {
  background:red;
}
.container div:nth-child(2) {
  background:yellow;
}
.container div:last-child {
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>blablabla<br>blablabla</div>
  <div>blablabla<br>blablabla</div>
  <div>blablabla<br>blablabla<br>blablabla<br>blablabla<br>blablabla<br>blablabla</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex`. Its great benefit is that your content will always remain responsive.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>Left</div>
  <div id="content">Content</div>
  <div>Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS **flex container**.

```
#container {
    display: flex;
}

#container div {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Check [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fazen/862xafus/2/) and [browser's support and issues](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) of "flex".

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

#container div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background-color: #ffc;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>left</div>
  <div>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br><br><br></div>
  <div>right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Click the `<>` and post the code here instead - also center the text

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex. The flex provides more comfort to divide the columns and provide same height to all those columns in the row.

```css
.flex-row {
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-box {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
}

.width-10 {
  width: 10%
}

.width-30 {
  width: 30%
}

.width-50 {
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row flex-box">
  <div class="width-10">...</div>
  <div class="width-10">...</div>
  <div class="width-30">...</div>
  <div class="width-50">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  background: #eee;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#container .col {
  position: relative;
  width: 27%;
  padding: 3%;
  float: left;
}

#container .col:nth-child(1) {
  left: 33%;
}

#container .col:nth-child(2) {
  left: -33.3%;
}

#container .col:nth-child(3) {
  left: 0;
}

#container:before,
#container:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 33.4%;
  width: 33.4%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}

#container:after {
  left: 66.667%;
  background: #eee;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="group">
  <div class="col">
    <h3>I am listed first in source order.</h3>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please in the future click the `<>` and create a [mcve] and also explain the main feature of your answer

Answer (score 0):

If a design is **NON-fluid** width, this task becomes considerably easier. When **fluid width** and **multiple columns** comes into play, this task becomes more difficult.

One way to sure-fire accomplish the idea of fluid width and equal height columns is using table cells. You can actually use plain div markup but still force it to behave like a table.

Besides using comfortable markup, we actually save some markup because we can go right from the table to the table cells. No element needs to simulate a table-row.

```
<style>
.container {
    display: table;
    /* Just if you need all viewport layout */
    /*position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;*/
}

.container .colum {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 25px;
}

.container .colum:nth-child(even) {
    background: #ccc;
}

.container .colum:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #eee;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="colum"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa non soluta dolor eveniet nulla delectus corrupti vero ex hic eos quam, ad, fugit totam, voluptatibus illum aliquid fugiat ea amet?</p></div>
    <div class="colum"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam iusto quos voluptates aliquam, sed sapiente rem voluptatum maxime? Vitae, quia. Omnis sit voluptatem accusantium! Numquam ab, sequi quisquam recusandae perferendis! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi quam repellat deleniti ipsam, nulla. Earum totam assumenda quos aspernatur, dolore aliquam ab perspiciatis illum consequuntur quo minima reprehenderit dignissimos, nisi!</p></div>
    <div class="colum"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis fugit placeat cum, nemo, ex delectus similique, doloribus a tempore aspernatur eum beatae cupiditate magnam. Odio repudiandae a, ab perferendis vero.</p></div>
</div>
```

This approach is fine, but they aren't supported in IE 7 so if you are interested in going this route I'd recommend just using actual table markup instead.

Another way, as usual, uses a wrapping element for all the columns. This wrapper is set to have hidden overflow, which not only clears the floated columns, but hides anything sticking outside of it. This is particularly important, because we are going to be forcing the height of the columns to be extremely tall, and then cutting them off with the hidden overflow.

The point here is that while we force the columns taller with a huge amount of bottom padding, we suck the height of the wrapper back up with an equal amount of negative bottom margin. This gives us just the effect we need.

```
<style>
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container .colum {
    width: 27%;
    padding: 30px 3.15% 0;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}

.container .colum:nth-child(even) {
    background: #ccc;
}

.container .colum:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #eee;
}
.container .colum p{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="colum"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque id hic, eius quae laborum ipsum corporis rem dolores accusamus provident ut perspiciatis nobis expedita obcaecati velit tenetur dolor, asperiores magni.</p></div>
    <div class="colum"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, dicta modi inventore molestiae excepturi, labore unde ea porro consectetur beatae eos, repellat perferendis sunt deleniti, velit ipsam vitae aliquam quisquam.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, neque, perspiciatis quod omnis, magnam in facilis reprehenderit aperiam, iusto laudantium nisi. Voluptas illum accusantium, odit alias eum. Esse, non, totam?</p></div>
    <div class="colum"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae exercitationem iure nihil in. Ut nostrum expedita, voluptatum saepe consectetur aut reiciendis dolor exercitationem, eligendi nulla facere eaque earum asperiores non.</p></div>    
</div>
```

Note that the padding on the bottoms of the columns is generated by the content within pushing down, as we can't count on bottom padding on the column itself, as it's busy with its fancy trick.